# Delete specific words + symbol in Bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a list of MAC vendors and I need to parse the text to delete information not necesary.

If  I have this

```
F8FEA8 Technico # Technico Japan Corporation
F8FF5F Shenzhen # Shenzhen Communication Technology Co.,Ltd
FC0012 ToshibaS # Toshiba Samsung Storage Technolgoy Korea Corporation
FC019E Vievu
FC01CD Fundacio # FUNDACION TEKNIKER
FC0647 Cortland # Cortland Research, LLC
FC0877 PrentkeR
FC0A81 Motorola # Motorola Solutions Inc.
```

I need to delete all ***[space][word][#]*** to have this

```
F8FEA8 Technico Japan Corporation
F8FF5F Shenzhen Communication Technology Co.,Ltd
FC0012 Toshiba Samsung Storage Technolgoy Korea Corporation
FC019E Vievu
FC01CD FUNDACION TEKNIKER
FC0647 Cortland Research, LLC
FC0877 PrentkeR
FC0A81 Motorola Solutions Inc.
```

Can it be done with **grep** or **sed** ? :S

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More `awk`

```
awk -F" # [^ ]+ " '{$1=$1}1' file # more robust
awk -F" # [^ ]+ " '$1=$1' file    # some dangerous, do not use if $1=0
```

This sets the field separator equal to what we like to remove then print the rest.

```
awk '{sub(/ # [^ ]+/,x)}1' file
```

This just remove what we do not want.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a shell only solution:

```
while read A B C D;do
  [ "$C" == "#" ] && echo "$A $D" || echo "$A $B $C $D"
done < infile.txt >outfile.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

This may work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri 's/\s\S+\s#//' file
```

or:

```
sed -i 's/ [^ ][^ ]* #//' file
```

Which mean: Look for a space followed by one or more non-spaces, followed by another space, followed by a `#` and then delete that expression. The file is update in place which is what the `-i` option means.The `-r` option in the first solution, allows `syntatic sugar` to be used, in this case the allows you to write `\S+` instead of `\S\+` or `[^ ][^ ]*`.

Comment: Any chance this can anchored such that it only kicks in when `#` is in the third field?

Comment: Thanks @1_CR as to the third field, maybe: `sed -r '/^(\S+\s){2}#/s/\s\S+\s#//' file`?

Answer (score 2):

It's seems an easy parsing. Here a solution using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl). It splits line in fields based in white spaces and if the third one is `#` remove it and the previous one:

```
perl -lane 'if ( $F[2] eq q|#| ) { @F = @F[0,3..$#F] }; print qq|@F|' infile
```

It yields:

```
F8FEA8 Technico Japan Corporation
F8FF5F Shenzhen Communication Technology Co.,Ltd
FC0012 Toshiba Samsung Storage Technolgoy Korea Corporation
FC019E Vievu
FC01CD FUNDACION TEKNIKER
FC0647 Cortland Research, LLC
FC0877 PrentkeR
FC0A81 Motorola Solutions Inc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `#` stands by itself in field 3 when it occurs, the following [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution may work

```
awk '$3 == "#"{t=$1; $1=$2=$3=""; sub(/^[[:space:]]+/, ""); $0=t" "$0}; 
     {print}' file.txt
```